# In Python, is there any way to test a generator object to find out which generator created it?

Tags: python

Given a generator object, is it possible to test whether it was created by a given generator? Perhaps better stated, is it possible to test what "type" of generator we have? Since generator objects have type `generator`, testing with `type` or `isinstance` will not work.

Consider the code below:

```
>>> def gen1():
...     yield 1
... 
>>> def gen2():
...     yield 2
... 
>>> g1 = gen1()
>>> g2 = gen2()
>>> 
>>> def do_something(f):
...     # need to know if f is a gen1 generator or a gen2 generator here
...     # isinstance(f, gen1)  raises a TypeError since gen1 is not a type
...     # type(f) is gen1 returns false
...     print(f)
... 
>>> do_something(g1)
<generator object gen1 at 0x100dcb370>
>>> do_something(g2)
<generator object gen2 at 0x100dcb3c0>
```

Note that if I were to implement the generator using an iterator class instead, then both `type` and `isinstance` would work, since the generated objects would be of the type given by the iterator class:

```
>>> class gen():
...     def __next__(self):
...          return 1
... 
>>> f = gen()
>>> type(f) is gen
True
>>> isinstance(f, gen)
True
```

Is it possible to achieve the same with simplicity (without doing things like wrapping the generator inside a class, or using a decorator, for example) with generators that are created using `yield`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the generating function (if any) is stored in the `__name__` attribute as a string.  If the string is all you needed, then you're done.

To get the actual function object, it's complicated.  The generator itself does not hold any reference to the function object, and the logic operates using a reference to a code object.

```
function object (`gen1`) -----> <code object >
                                    ^
generator object (`g1`)  -----------╯
```

Armed with the generator function's original name, you could conceivably use `getattr` on the containing module to try and retrieve the originating function.  This method is not necessarily reliable: there is an assumption here that the function object still exists and is still bound to that name.  However, it's possible that the name has been deleted or rebound.   In CPython, the function could also have been garbage collected already if the reference count decreased to 0.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Any idea why `type` does not return the generator function, like it does for objects created by classes? It's a inconsistent with the rest of Python I think.

Comment: Actually, it is not inconsistent - I think you are just misunderstanding the object model.  `gen1` is an instance of `types.FunctionType` and `g1` is an instance of `types.GeneratorType`

Comment: To see where you might be going wrong consider this - if `g1` was an instance of `gen1`, then what would `g1_ = (1 for x in 'abc')` be an instance of?

Comment: I agree that `gen1` should of type `FunctionType` but I still think `g1` should of type `gen1` to be consistent with the rest of Python. Consider the fact that the type of a class is its metaclass, and the type of an object is its class. In other words, the type of objects are set to the object that creates them. Metaclasses creating classes, and classes creating objects, for example.

Comment: But `gen1` is just a name, it is not a type!

Comment: As for you question,  I think that would the difference between an `g1` and `g1_` should the difference between an object of known class type and an object of an "anonymous" class, which Python does not support, but conceptually that is how I see those two to be different. In other words, I see `(1 for x in 'abc')` to be an "anonymous" generator. (Which are called generator expressions in Python.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49693/discussion-between-sahand-and-wim)

Comment: Why do you say python doesn't support an anonymous class?  Try this:  `type('anonymous class', (), {'foo': 1, 'bar': 'hello im an attr'})().bar`

Comment: You really seem to be missing the point - in python there are only names and objects.  And *an object can exist with many names bound to it, and indeed without any name bound to it*.  What would be the point in distinguishing between the type of generators created by genexs and the type of genexs created by generator functions?  What if I created a generator instance from a generator function, and then I deleted all names pointing at the generator function?  Would my generator instance then magically transform itself from a `gen1` generator into an "anonymous" generator?

Comment: You can do that with classes too. And no, it wouldn't, because the generator is itself a function object living in memory, so generator instances would still have their type equal to the generator function object that is in memory, regardless of what you do with the names.

Comment: Even with a class, I can do `class C(object): pass` and then `c = C()` and finally `C = "whatever"` and `type(c)` is still defined and points to the class object. What happens with generators would be analogous to all objects having type `object` regardless of what class is used to create them.

Comment: Hmm, well that is true.  But there is still the fact that `gen1` is just a name.  Since you agree that `gen1` should of type `FunctionType`, what exactly should be the name pointing to this hypothetical `gen1` type?  Of course you can't use "gen1", because you've already agreed that's pointing to the instance of `FunctionType` :)

Comment: With classes it gets set to the name that you use to define the class, but that is just convention.  `Foo = type('Bar', (), {})` for example will bind a different name to the class, so you create `Bar` instances by calling `Foo()`.

Comment: The way I'm thinking about this, I would expect `gen1` to have type `type` similar to classes, and have name `gen1` assigned to it, again, exactly like a class would. Then if we have `g = gen1()` we would have `type(g)` equal to the object of type `type` that is `gen1`. (Names really don't matter. I'm concerned about how the objects are related to each other, through their types. Names are secondary :) )

Comment: Actually, I just checked after writing that and turns out `FunctionType` is derived from `type` (that is, `isinstance(types.FunctionType, type)` is in fact `True`) so `gen1` could continue to be of type `FunctionType` and we could still have `type(g1)` as `gen1`. In fact, `isinstance(type(g1), type)` would still be `True` which makes sense.

Comment: Well, I don't know the answer to your question then.  Maybe it's just that generators were intended to be very simple objects (just fancy functions really) that don't have to have all the overhead of a class.  It doesn't smell right to me to have a new type created every time you want to use a generator.  Should every possible function also invisibly create a type which "fathers" just that function?  What would be the use of that type in the first place?  If you are looking a factory which instantiates more of those generators, you just have to call the generator function again.

Comment: Fair enough. I might ask that as a separate question once I think about it over again later. Thanks for the discussion :)